# t-test for likert scales questionnaire

Tags: t-test, likert, survey-sampling

I am working on a research assessment where I intend to ask individuals to submit a questionnaire based on  public perceptions of national security. Participants will answer statements based on a 5-point likert scale (Strongly Agree, Agree, Neutral, Disagree, Strongly Disagree).

I want to compare their answers on soft security concerns vs military threats so half the statements will refer to each.

Can I use a t-test to determine if their is a statistically significant difference between the two sets of answers?

Comment: Welcome to this site. Did you review our closely [related threads](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Blikert%5D+t+test)?

Comment: Too vague to answer. // I assume each subject gets questions on soft and military security? How many questions on each type? So each subject has a Soft total $S$ and a Mil total $M$. Several possible comparisons come to mind. Are you interested is seeing whether $S-M$ tends to be pos or neg across all subjects? In whether someone with hi $S$ also has hi $M?$ // If you were to do a t test, exactly what would null and alt hypotheses be? // Treating (ordinal categorical) Likert data as if numerical is controversial. Have you considered using nonparametric Wilcoxon tests instead of t tests.